# SQL Server 2008 : TSQL, select same data for different times based on column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using mssql 2008 R2,

i have below structure

```
    create table #temp (
    product int,
    [order] int,
    ord_qnty int
    )

    insert #temp 
    select 10 ,3,4
```

now, if ord_qnty is 4 , i want to select same product,order four times but in all four rows thevalue of ord_qnty should be 1 , i.e.

out put should be

```
    Product order ord_qnty
    10      3     1
    10      3     1
    10      3     1
    10      3     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
      product INT
    , [order] INT
    , ord_qnty INT
)
INSERT @temp(product, [order], ord_qnty) 
SELECT 10, 3, 4

SELECT  
      t.product
    , t.[order]
    , ord_qnty = 1 
FROM @temp t
JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values sv ON t.ord_qnty > sv.number
WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'

SELECT  
      t.product
    , t.[order]
    , ord_qnty = 1 
FROM @temp t
JOIN (
    SELECT number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM sys.system_parameters p    
) sv ON t.ord_qnty >= sv.number
```

**Output:**

```
product     order       ord_qnty
----------- ----------- -----------
10          3           1
10          3           1
10          3           1
10          3           1
```

**Query Cost:**

[image: proff]

**For any "millions value":**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @numbers TABLE (number INT)

DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
      product INT
    , [order] INT
    , ord_qnty INT
)
INSERT @temp(product, [order], ord_qnty) 
SELECT 10, 3, 4

DECLARE 
      @i BIGINT = 1
    , @max BIGINT = (
            SELECT MAX(ord_qnty)
            FROM @temp 
        )

WHILE (@i <= @max) BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @numbers (number) 
    VALUES (@i), (@i+1), (@i+2), (@i+3), (@i+4), (@i+5), (@i+6), (@i+7), (@i+8), (@i+9)
    SELECT @i += 10

END

SELECT 
      t.product
    , t.[order]
    , ord_qnty = 1 
FROM @temp t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @numbers
    WHERE number < @max + 1
) t2
```

Comment: @Nishad, may I ask what you did not like in my answer?

Comment: THerz nothing tht i did not like :)  , anything there , y u asking ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a numbers table, you can use that. If not, you can generate one:

```
;with Numbers(n) as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) from sys.objects
)
select product,[order],1 as ord_qnty
from #temp t inner join Numbers num
    on t.ord_qnty >= num.n
```

(In my nearly empty scratch database, the `ROW_NUMBER()` generates 77 rows. If that's not going to be enough, you can introduce cross-joins or use other tricks to generate more numbers, or you can create and populate a permanent numbers table)